# Unity3D materials not displaying, but being set correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to dynamically load an object, and color each sub-object based on the state of it taken from a file on someone's computer.

Loading the object is fine, and the material is being set, but this coloring is not working in the scene while the game is running. I am doing this like this:

```
grandchild.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.EnableKeyword("_NORMALMAP");

grandchild.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color.yellow);
```

When viewing the scene, this color is not visible (the object color is the same as its original color.
I then decided to try changing the material itself to a colored one like this:

```
grandchild.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = (Material)Resources.Load("YellowMaterial", typeof(Material);
```

This did not work either, the material is being set (going into the scene editor and viewing the object properties shows the correct material), but the object is not changing color and instead keeps it's default. However, taking a material in the assets folder and manually dragging it to the object in the scene editor *does* work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Here are some pictures of what I'm talking about

The object in the inspector (After material change):

[image]

The object in the scene:

[image]

Materials Properties:
[image]

Comment: Did you try `grandchild.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.yellow;`?

Comment: @derHugo Hi! Yes I did, and to the same effect. The color in the inspector changed, but it didn't change visually.

Comment: Can you attach a Screenshot of the SceneView and the Inspector? Is it possible that the object has more than one material and you probably change the wrong one?

Comment: @derHugo Just attached two links to the photos.

Comment: @derHugo Is there something different between dragging-and-dropping a material into an object and what I'm doing besides changing the default material? Because dragging and dropping it achieves the desired effect, but I need this change to be done at runtime

Comment: Your obect is hard to see ... Do you have any lights in your scene?

Comment: @derHugo Yes but it was too zoomed in. I zoomed out now, does that give you a better view?

Comment: Better ;) could you also unfold the material properties? The issue might be the normal map maybe? You also said `taking a material in the assets folder and manually dragging it to the object in the scene editor does work.` does this work with this material you try to apply or only with others?

Comment: @derHugo Just added another picture with the Materials properties. Also it works with every material including the one I'm using in this example, just not when done programmatically

Comment: @derHugo I currently don't have a normal map, or a height map for that matter. Do I need that, and how would I set this up?

Comment: Is the object you're dealing with a multi-material mesh? Are there multiple renderers returned if you get all the `renderer` components?

Comment: @GarrettJohnson Nope, currently just with a single Mesh Renderer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GarrotJohnson and derHugo gave me an idea of what the problem could be. It turns out, each of the objects I was working with had a child object (called "default" for some reason), which has its own Mesh Renderer and default material. Getting this child object (GameObject.transform.GetChild(0)) and changing that material works.