# When changing the colour of a prefab using a c#script, it shows in the inspector but not in the game view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a prefab at runtime and be able to assign a colour to it. When my prefab is a simple cylinder this all works fine using:

```
var renderer = new_c.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
renderer.material.color = Color.green;
```

but when I try it with my arrow prefab (an imported object), the colour shows up in the inspector but not in the game view of the prefab instance.

I'm thinking it might have something to do with the fact that in the hierarchy, the arrow's body is a child of the prefab but I'm not sure? 
I've tried calling:

```
new_c.GetComponentInChildren<GameObject>().GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.green;

new_c.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color.green);

GetCompentsInChildren<Meshrenderer>.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.green);
```

but it still doesn't work most of the time.
Sometimes it works and the arrow is green, and sometimes it stays the colour of the default material. I can't seem to find any difference between the instances that work and those that don't,
this has been driving me crazy all day, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I expected the arrow to turn green but it only does this sometimes and I get no error messages and the inspector says that the material is green but in the game view and scene view it is not

[picture showing the inspector window where the material is green and the game view where the arrow is still default material coloured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt3BL.png)

Comment: Are you using baked or realtime lighting?

Comment: In scene mode it's realtime but in game mode it's using AR (Vuforia) so I've not included any other light in the scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it after days of searching!
Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54008057/11829883

Because the arrows body was a child of the arrow model which was a child of the actual arrow prefab, I had to call `GetChild(0)` twice on the object - for some reason `GetComponentInChildren` wasn't working so i assumed that wasn't the issue

This is the line of code that fixed it:

```
new_c.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.yellow;
```